# In place recovery of 6 TB external hard drive (repair File Allocation Table)

Tags: gratis, hard-disk, data-recovery

I have a 6 TB external hard drive which suddenly does not show up in the Windows Explorer (so, I can't run Chkdsk on it).

Disk Manager doesn't give me many options, other than to format.

I *could* run some undeleter, but that would reccover to an  external drive - and I don't have one that large.

Is there any gratis program that will help me repair the file table in-situ?

The disk was formatted for Windows (exFat), buy I will recover from any o/s.

I am not looking for file by file recovery (undelete), but for  File Allocation Table repair

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but 1) Try using the file manager on the [Home Partition Wizard by MiniTool](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) and 2) try their [recovery software](http://www.minitool.com/data-recovery-software/power-data-recovery-free.html), I've had great luck with their software, just try their free versions and see what it picks up.

Comment: I love the partition tool & have used it for years (+1). Alas, it cannot help. And I can't afford USD 60 for soemthing that might help, or might not. I will update the question & tag it `gratis`

Comment: The situation you describe sounds a lot like a broken MBR rather than a broken FAT. What makes you think you need to repair the FAT? If you have additional details in this regard, they could help.

Comment: This is not a bootable disk (sorry, I shoudl have said that), so I don't see that it is an MBR porblem. When a whole single disk partition changes from fine to invisible, I always think of the FAT - what do you reckon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Linux System Rescue CD](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) can be burnt onto a CD or USB drive and when booted from offers lots of tools to repair your system, (even if it is a windows system).

- Includes partition editing tools, (GParted & GNU Parted)
- [sfdisk](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sfdisk) and
- [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) which can:

  - Fix partition table, recover deleted partition
  - Recover FAT32 boot sector from its backup
  - Rebuild FAT12/FAT16/FAT32 boot sector
  - Fix FAT tables
  - Rebuild NTFS boot sector
  - Recover NTFS boot sector from its backup
  - Fix MFT using MFT mirror
  - Locate ext2/ext3/ext4 Backup SuperBlock
  - Undelete files from FAT, exFAT, NTFS and ext2 filesystem
  - Copy files from deleted FAT, exFAT, NTFS and ext2/ext3/ext4 partitions.